Message Bus subscription to item in CollectionProperty
I am trying to create a 'Message Bus' subscription to an item in a 'bpy.types.CollectionProperty'. For example, I register a collection like so:
import bpy


class MyProperty(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):

    my_float: bpy.props.FloatProperty()

# have some panel to change the property
class MyPanel(bpy.types.Panel):

    bl_label = "My Property"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_context = "objectmode"
    bl_category = "addon"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        for item in context.scene.my_collection:
            layout.prop(item, "my_float")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyProperty)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_collection = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(
        type=MyProperty
    )
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MyProperty)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_collection
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MyPanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

Then, I add a subscription to the first item in the collection, e.g. using this script:
import bpy

# add some items to clean collection
bpy.context.scene.my_collection.clear()
for _ in range(13):
    bpy.context.scene.my_collection.add()


def msgbus_callback():
    print("Something changed!")


bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
    key=bpy.context.scene.my_collection[0].path_resolve("my_float", False),
    owner=bpy.context.scene,
    args=(),
    notify=msgbus_callback,
    options={"PERSISTENT"}
)

This works as expected right after creating the subscription, printing 'Something Changed!' to the console after changing the first item. However, after adding a certain number of items to the collection, e.g.:
for _ in range(13):
    bpy.context.scene.my_collection.add()

at some point, the msgbus callback doesn't work anymore. Presumable, this is due to memory re-allocation of the collection. Is there any safe way to have a message bus subscription to an item in a CollectionProperty?
Btw, I know I could define an 'update' function when declaring the 'my_float' property, but I'm just curious if this would be at all possible, since it could lead to cleaner code in some situations.
Thanks ! :D
